# How to pass a args from a jQuery defered

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred, promise

I have a Backbone model that fetch some data, process the data and then a function should get the processed data.

```
$.when(model.fetch())
  .done(function(){
    return model.processData()
  })
  .then(function(processedData){
    //make something with the processed data
  })
```

Unfortunately the `then` method get the result from the `model.fetch()` call and not the return value of the `done` function

Comment: Replace `done` with `then`. See http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/.

Comment: That was fast, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.then` instead of `.done`. `.then` returns a new promise which is resolved with the value the callback function returns.

`.done` on the other hand returns the original promise object and the return value of the callback is simply ignored.

More information can be found in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (emphasize mine):

> As of jQuery 1.8, the `deferred.then()` method returns a new promise that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a function, replacing the now-deprecated `deferred.pipe()` method. The `doneFilter` and `failFilter` functions filter the original deferred's resolved / rejected status and values. The `progressFilter` function filters any calls to the original deferred's `notify` or `notifyWith` methods. **These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the promise's `.done()` or `.fail()` callbacks**, or they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks. If the filter function used is `null`, or not specified, the promise will be resolved or rejected with the same values as the original.

Answer (score 1):

To *intercept*, *modify* or *filter* data from a `done` handler to further calls, you can use the `.pipe()` method.

Even if in your example, you could just entirely replace the `.done()`, with your `.then` handler directly, it could also look like:

```
$.when(model.fetch())
  .pipe(function() {
      return model.processData();
  })
  .then(function(processedData){
    //make something with the processed data
  });
```

Of course this doesn't make too much sense as mentioned above, but think about the possibilites of `.pipe()` anyway. It can be a very handy tool.

Comment: `.pipe` is deprecated now though. This behavior was added to `.then`.

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't know that it was declared as deprecated, I'll have a read.

Comment: There was a long discussion about it afaik. It was done to comply more with the original CommonJS Promises/A proposal: http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A.

Comment: I just read the wiki and the jQuery doc about it and I have to say, I don't like it at all. `.then` now seems way to overloaded IMO and not very convenient too. Anyway `.pipe` will be gone sooner or later so we have to deal with it.

Comment: Once you've got your mind round `.then()`, it becomes your best friend.

Comment: I didn't like it at first either. But it makes it compatible with other promise libraries, which is good IMO.

Answer (score 1):

`$.when()` should not be necessary.

Here are two possibilities :

```
model.fetch().then(function() {
    return model.processData()
}).then(function(processedData){
    //make something with the processed data
});
```

or, if `processData()` is synchronous :

```
model.fetch().done(function() {
    var foo = model.processData();
    //make something with the processed data, foo
});
```